# Upsert many violates unique constraint in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I am trying to upsert contact records in Postgres based on a partial unique index (called `contacts_unique_idx`) on a jsonb `data`column, a boolean `deleted` column, and a `duplicated` boolean column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX contacts_uniqueness_idx  ON contacts(
(data->>'customerId'),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'location'->>'formatted', '')), LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'given', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'middlename', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'surname', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'suffix', '')), LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'title', ''))
)
    WHERE deleted = false and duplicated = false
```

My upsert function (below, with `values` removed for brevity) successfully inserts a single contact record and multiple contact records if they do not already exist. It also successfully updates an existing record if I pass in a single value to upsert, building a new jsonb object on the `data` column based on the existing record data and updated record data as per the `DO UPDATE` part of the function.

On passing more than one value to upsert, however, I receive an error: `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "contacts_unique_idx"`, the unique constraint on which the update is supposed to occur.

```
INSERT INTO contacts (id, data)
VALUES ({uuid} :: {dataObject} jsonb)
ON CONFLICT (
(data->>'customerId'),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'location'->>'formatted', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'given', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'middlename', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'surname', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'suffix', '')),
LOWER(COALESCE(data->'data'->'profile'->'name'->'anglican'->>'title', ''))
      )
      WHERE deleted = false and duplicated = false
      DO UPDATE
      SET data =
      jsonb_build_object(
        'id', contacts.id,
        'data', jsonb_build_object(
          'fields',(contacts.data->'data'->>'fields')::jsonb || (excluded.data->'data'->>'fields')::jsonb,
          'profile',(excluded.data->'data'->>'profile')::jsonb,
          'status',contacts.data->'data'->>'status',
          'contacted',contacts.data->'data'->>'contacted',
          'successful',contacts.data->'data'->>'successful',
          'reservation',(contacts.data->'data'->>'reservation')::jsonb
        ),
        'meta', jsonb_build_object(
          'etag',contacts.data->'meta'->>'etag',
          'created',contacts.data->'meta'->>'created',
          'modified',excluded.data->'meta'->>'modified',
          'resource',contacts.data->'meta'->>'resource',
          'createdBy',contacts.data->'meta'->>'createdBy',
          'isDeleted',contacts.data-> 'meta'->>'isDeleted',
          'modifiedBy',excluded.data->'meta'->>'modifiedBy'
        ),
        'customerId',contacts.data->>'customerId',
        'securityGroupId',contacts.data->>'securityGroupId'
      )
      RETURNING *;
```

Is this a concurrency issue? Why can I upsert a single record but not multiple?

Comment: I didn't check exactly, but could it be that the `UPDATE` violates the constraint?

Comment: For anyone that's wondering, using a nested `jsonb_set` to update `data` and `meta` instead of using `jsonb_build_object` resolved the issue.